# Monorepo organization npm

Tags: npm, expo, nestjs, package.json, monorepo

I have a monorepo where i store my nestjs app and expo react native app
`/apps/nestjs`
`/apps/expo`
package.json

this is my main package.json

```
    "name": "monorepo",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    
    "workspaces": [
        "apps/*"
    ]
}
```

and my apps have their own package json
when i run `npm i`
the node_modules folder appears in the root of the monorepo and some dependencies installing into node_modules folder for my applications
`/apps/nestjs/node_modules`
`/apps/expo/node_modules`

I want to get rid of the node_modules folder in the root of the project and install all dependencies directly to the `/apps/nestjs/node_modules` `/apps/expo/node_modules`
so at the end i will have node modules folder for each of my applications